# How to… using MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I'm trying to use MigLayout for my project but i'm struggling to understand the logic.

I'd like to place 2 labels on top and at the bottom of a certain panel with a margin of 20px between the labels and the ends of the panel.

Moreover, he labels must be centered horizontally.

Any ideas on how to do this ?

Comment: It *is* a duplicate, please read the documentation, it should answer your question.

Comment: It's not duplicate. I'm not asking for the documentation, I'm asking for a solution to my specific question !!

Comment: You might consider demonstrating some ideas you've tried that haven't worked

Comment: Also you might want to change your title........

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried something like this : add(footerLabel, "gapbottom  20px, center") but it doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this (we could use insets instead of gaptop/bottom for example). Here is a simple example:

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill"));
p.add(new JLabel("1"), "top, gaptop 20px, center, wrap");
p.add(new JLabel("2"), "bottom, gapbottom 20px, center");
```

The above example uses `top` and `bottom` to position the labels at the top and bottom of the panel. A more realistic example, where we have content between these labels, may be something like this:

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.setLayout(new MigLayout("debug, fill, insets 20 0 20 0", "", "[][grow][]"));
p.add(new JLabel("Top"), "center, wrap");
p.add(new JLabel("Center"), "center, grow, wrap");
p.add(new JLabel("Bottom"), "center");
```

This example uses insets for the desired 20px gap top and bottom, this way the 20px gap isnt added to the labels row.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Labels are positioned well on the top and the bottom but they are not centered on their row. Any other way to do this?

Comment: Check my edit, I added a second example which I believe addresses this.